# Filter an array containing a list of articles as Objects

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array containing 7 objects, all of the articles. I need to be able to show only the first 3 articles

```js
const myArray = [
   {
      id: "article_1",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_2",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_3",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_4",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_5",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_6",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_7",
      type: "articles"
   }
]

const filteredArticles = myArray.filter(article => myArray.length > 3)

console.log(filteredArticles)
```

Unfortunately, it returns an empty array instead of an array with articles.

I know a solution could be to use if(myArray.length > 3) { //show only index 0, 1, 2, 3 } else { // blah blah}

But I am trying to use js .filter which should easily hide the number of articles over 3.

Comment: You should look at [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: myArray.slice(0, 3) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
myArray.filter((_,i) => i < 3)
```

```js
const myArray = [
   {
      id: "article_1",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_2",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_3",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_4",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_5",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_6",
      type: "articles"
   },
{
      id: "article_7",
      type: "articles"
   }
]

const filteredArticles = myArray.filter((_,i) => i < 3);

console.log(filteredArticles);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of the callback passed to filter is the current index.  So you can do something like:

```
const filteredArticles = myArray.filter((article, i) => {
    return i < 3;
});
```

That would be truthy for only the first three elements, so you're filtered array would be the first three.  Keep in mind that filter will still check the rest of the array, so there might be a more performant way of doing this.

EDIT: As some commenters have mentions, .slice would be a better way of doing this as you don't have to then iterate over the rest of the array as in the filter solution.